# Oracle PL/SQL statements not being recognised by SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have 11g 32bit Oracle Express installed on a 64bit laptop. 
Any pl/sql statements/ syntax is being seen as an error by sql plus and only sql code is being recognized.

Must be an Oracle config problem somewhere. This is a fresh install of Oracle Express after experiencing the same problem on the previous install.

Anybody else have this problem? I've googled this to death and not come up with a solution.

```
Set serveroutput on
Set echo off
Remark  *** Set up the SQL*Plus environment ***

Set Pagesize 24
Set Feedback Off

Remark  *** Format the Columns ***
Column  ctype   Format A5       Heading Car|Type
Column  A       Format A3       Heading A
Column  B       Format A3       Heading B
Column  C       Format A3       Heading C
Column  D       Format A3       Heading D
Column  E       Format A3       Heading E
Column  F       Format A3       Heading F
Column  G       Format A3       Heading G

break on ctype

Remark  *** The Query ***
DECLARE
    v_cid   VARCHAR2(3);
    v_grade CHAR(1);
BEGIN
    FOR ct IN (SELECT c_type# as ct FROM consultant)
    LOOP
        v_cid := ct;
        SELECT      c_type# as ctype,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'A')) as A,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'B')) as B,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'C')) as C,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'D')) as D,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'E')) as E,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'F')) as F,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'G')) as G
        FROM        consultant
        WHERE       consultant.c_type# = v_cid
        GROUP BY    c_type#
        ORDER BY    ctype;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT      car_type.c_type# as ctype,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'A')) as A,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'B')) as B,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'C')) as C,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'D')) as D,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'E')) as E,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'F')) as F,
            TO_CHAR((SELECT count(grade) FROM consultant WHERE grade = 'G')) as G
FROM        consultant
INNER JOIN  grade
ON          consultant.grade = grade.grade
INNER JOIN  car_type
ON          consultant.c_type# = car_type.c_type#
GROUP BY    car_type.c_type#
ORDER BY    ctype
/
Remark  *** Reset the environment ***
Clear columns
Ttitle Off
Btitle Off
Set Feedback on
Set Pagesize 20 
Set Echo on

Error code :  ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Comment: Post the statement and the **exact** error message.

Comment: edited my original post to reflect the code.

Comment: and any pl sql code like DECLARE, BEGIN is throwing errors. No sql errors though.

Comment: How do you run these statements in SQLplus? I guess you don't type them in each time you try them.

Comment: ed , paste them into notepad , save and "/" + enter

Comment: and, of course, saving them as xxx.sql and running them as a script "@xxx

Comment: 'Any PL/SQL statement/syntax' - what's the minimal code that throws an ORA-00922? As well as the incorrect cursor reference jonearles pointed out, your select inside the loop isn't selecting *into* anything.

Comment: I've actually moved to another machine and there are no errors with the code at all. I have tried uninstalling 11g following the Oracle Docs guidelines on a manual uninstall, re- installed 11g Express after a reboot and still managed to get the same errors. However on the new machine everything is fine. I'm giving up on this as a corrupt something somewhere and as it is not a production environment I am not going to fuss about it too much as I don't have the time. Seems its an uncommon issue and was hoping for a known fix to be offered up by someone who'd perhaps had the same experience.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
v_cid := ct;
```

with

```
v_cid := ct.ct;
```

The code must reference `cursor_name.column_name`, even if the cursor and column names are identical.  Also it always helps to reduce problems to the smallest possible size.

Comment: Thanks for that one, however no difference on error. SQL Plus seems to have taken a dislike to PL SQL and refuses to acknowledge its existence. Since moved to a new machine and all is well with the code.

Comment: Does even a trivial PL/SQL block like this fail in SQL*Plus:  `exec null;`

Answer (score -5):

The free Oracle Express doesn't support PlSql